# Concurrent queue dequeue

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, concurrent-queue

I am using concurrent queue and dequeue the data from queue via multiple threads by creation Action delegate

```
Action action = () =>
        {
            SubscriptionResponseModel subsModel;
            while (concurrentQueue.TryTake(out subsModel))
            {
                MakeTransactionAndAddIntoQueue(subsModel);
            }
        };
```

And invoke this action delegate parallel multiple threads

```
Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);
```

I want to know one thing when I am using `SubscriptionResponseModel subsModel;` in multiple actions is it thread safe?.

Comment: What is SubscriptionResponseModel

Comment: That depends on *Your* implementation of `SubscriptionResponseModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of the `action` will have its own `subsModel` - so using it to get value from the queue is thread safe.

Case when it would not be thread safe is when you *capture* variable from outside context:

```
    // ********** Code showing non-thread safe case **************
    SubscriptionResponseModel subsModel;
    Action action = () =>
    {
        // all invocations of `action` will share subsModel as it is captured.
        while (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out subsModel))
        {
            MakeTransactionAndAddIntoQueue(subsModel);
        }
    };
```

Notes:

- whether or not using properties/methods of the `SubscriptionResponseModel` is thread safe depends on that type.
- there is a very good chance that running multiple `TryDequeue` in parallel will not improve performance at all. `Parallel.Invoke` of multiple busy loops will simply block more than one thread constantly querying empty queue.

Comment: If I want to consume my concurrent queue parallely how could we do this? Is that right way what i am doing in above example. Please suggest

Comment: @maheshsharma code you have in the post achieves what you want. Is it actually useful for your task is up to you. You may want to ask separate question on better ways of achieving your actual goal (it is unlikely that whole point of your code is "to consume my concurrent queue parallely" - make sure to add real usage scenario if asking new question)